# The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Tags: typescript

tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- tsc helloworld.ts
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: did you install typescript globally or package-local only?

Comment: I was installed typescript using this line of code npm install -g typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart your command prompt after the installation of TypeScript, because its environment variables aren't updated while it's open.

Answer (score 6):

tsc -init

if it does not working **try add npx**

**npx tsc -init**